# Combine PDF in Rails with combine_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, merge

I'm trying to use the gem `combine_pdf` in order to combine a number of PDFs in my app. They are located in `assets/forms/packages/1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf`.

I'm trying to following the gem's guide but the code yields an error:

```
@pdfForms = CombinePDF.new
@pdfForms << CombinePDF.new('assets/forms/packages/1.pdf')
```

I get a runtime error:

```
root is unknown - cannot determine if file is Encrypted
```

Any help is much appreciated, or another way to merge pdfs. The gem `pdf-merge` fails with my app due to its dependency on `rjb`.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you running ? Have you ran a test in a shell command like `pdftk assets/forms/packages/{1,2,3}.pdf cat output out.pdf` ? What is the output ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open a file by using

File.open("assets/forms/packages/1.pdf")

If this is not working then your file path is wrong.
If this pdf file is in your app/assets folder of your application then you can access it by using:

```
file_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "forms", "packages","1.pdf")

File.open(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CombinePDF.load` instead of `CombinePDF.new`.

`new` will try both loading the file and parsing the string - so you won't see the file loading exceptions.

It could be that the file path is wrong and CombinePDF is trying to parse 'assets/forms/packages/1.pdf' as if it were the content of a PDF file.

Your code should look like this:

```
@pdfForms = CombinePDF.new
@pdfForms << CombinePDF.load('assets/forms/packages/1.pdf')
```